# Why does MvvmCross create a new ViewModel when back button is pressed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

I'm building a Windows 8.1 mobile app with MVVMCross and I noticed some strange behavior when navigating between viewmodels.

I have 2 Viewmodels like so...

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
   public override void Start()
   {
      base.Start();
   }

   public void Init()
   {
      //init code here
   }
   ...
   private void GoForward()
   {
        ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>();
   }
}

public class SecondViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
   private void GoBack()
   {
      Close(this);
   }
}
```

When I call Close(this) on SecondViewModel, Mvvmcross calls Start() and Init() on FirstViewModel again, like it was tombstoned.

Why does this happen? Even if I only leave FirstViewModel for a couple seconds, it seems to be tombstoned immediately. How do I stop this from happening? It's frustrating because I now have to maintain the state of FirstViewModel constantly.

Comment: Have you tried setting `NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;` in your page constructor?

Comment: No - I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: @KristianVukusic - This works great, thanks! I'm used to iOS which caches everything automatically. I also discovered that if you want to remove the page from the cache (which I want to do when user heads to a different section of the app), you can change it back to NavigationCacheMode.Disabled.

Please go ahead and "answer" the question so I can give you the appropriate credit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write the following line of code in your page constructor. This enables the caching of visited pages.

`NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;`